# “installation of package tuneR had non-zero exit status” in R

Tags: r, tuner

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
R version: 3.4.3 and 3.4.4

I tried to install tuneR with install.packages("tuneR") in R 3.4.3 and R 3.4.4 but I get this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘signal’ ...
 package ‘signal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c dpchim.f -o dpchim.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:182: recipe for target 'dpchim.o' failed
make: *** [dpchim.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘signal’
* removing ‘/home/helias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/signal’
ERROR: dependency ‘signal’ is not available for package ‘tuneR’
* removing ‘/home/helias/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tuneR’
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpL1f4HR/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tuneR") :
  installation of package ‘signal’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tuneR") :
  installation of package ‘tuneR’ had non-zero exit status
```

(I also used RStudio)

Comment: Have you tried installing from the git repo? I have found this to help before, but only with other packages, <https://github.com/cran/tuneR>

Comment: No, I didn't, anyway I solved installing gfortran, I missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved installing gfortran and after re-run install.packages("tuneR")

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading the source and install from RStudio. tuneR is available at:

https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tuneR

Download the .tar.gz file and install locally. You can install using through RStudio (Packages tab -> change install from: Package), or you can install through the terminal using

```
R CMD INSTALL -l /path tuneR.tar.gz
```

Another option is

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("cran/tuneR")
```